# How does one set default Ignore options for TortoiseGit?

Tags: git, tortoisegit

Every time I click the Add to Ignore List command in the TortoiseGit explorer context menu, I get a popup asking where the .gitIgnore file must be, and whether I want to ignore only top level items, or recursively.

I can't find any setting inside TortoiseGit, but I may have missed something. How can I set defaults for this and avoid the ever present and annoying dialogue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Up to TortoiseGit 1.7.15, there is no configurable default options for ignore file, nor the ignore dialog remembers last selected options.

Comment: Well then, that is bloody annoying.